# .htaccess — как запретить доступ к папке и вложенным в неё файлам?

Tags: .htaccess

И **вложенным** в эту папку файлам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в папке с файлами которые надо запретить следует разместить файл .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ~ "\.(php|htm|html|js)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 4):

Хватит и одной строчки в `.htaccess`

```
Deny from all
```

Файл положить в папку, которую надо закрыть. Все что лежит в папке будет закрыто.

Comment: ilovetrancekrsk ну ты и посоветовал =) давай все страницы засунем в папку а все скрипты ссылки итд которые ссылались на него проигнорируем, и все ради 1 строчки =)

Comment: Я посоветовал, и при чем абсолютно верно. В ответе Quiss необходимо указывать расширение файла - все не укажешь.
И если уж на то пошло, то в нормальной структуре в корне будет лежать хтакцес, который закрывает вообще все, а те папки которые нужно открыть, например, с картинками, в них лежит свой файл, который открывает эту папку.

Answer (score 3):

Для предотвращения просмотра директорий сайта добавьте в .htaccess следующий код:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

[Источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/165701/) - Хабрахабр.

Comment: Если ничего не путаю, этот код запрещает пользователям смотреть, какие файлы лежат в папках, но к самим файлам доступ остаётся, — т. е. Вы не ответили именно на поставленный вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, но там есть и другие "шпаргалки".