# .htaccess — как запретить доступ к .css файлам?

Tags: css, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть файл `main.css`, который доступен по прямой ссылке http://test4.dev.3klika.ru/main.css

В `.htacccess` содержатся строки:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(css|)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

но файл доступен как при подключении в `<head>`, так и по прямой ссылке.

---

Мне необходимо перенаправлять все запросы .css файлов на .php файл, который будет сжимать стили и сохранять в кэш файл, поэтому вариант "удалить файл" - не подходит.

---

redroid, спасибо за ответ.

Проблема как раз в том, что имея запись в .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*).css$  /t.php  [L]
```

И при переходе по ссылке http://test4.dev.3klika.ru/css/main.css, я получаю именно .css файл, а не .php. (Файл .php есть, доступен, содержит банальный print());

Comment: Зачем запрещать доступ к стилям? Удалите файлы тогда.

Comment: С точки зрения сервера нет никакой разницы между ссылкой в head (link) и прямой ссылкой.

Comment: Странный сервис, где я не могу оставлять комментарии из за отсутствия рейтинга. Мне необходимо перенаправлять все запросы .css файлов на .php файл, который будет сжимать стили и сохранять в кэш файл, поэтому вариант "удалить файл" - не подходит.

Comment: @ВикторБарзилович Похоже, вы задали вопрос с одной учётки, а дополняете с другой - потому и не можете комментировать собственный вопрос. Отправлю заявку на то, чтобы объединить учётки. Комментарии где угодно можно будет оставлять после набора 50 репутации, это довольно быстро делается и нужно для защиты сайта от спама.

Comment: У вас везде 500 какието ошибки , возможно как раз в .htaccess мб вы пытаетесь использовать модули apache которые не установлены?

Answer (score 2):

По поводу сжатия на лету , я делаю так , ставлю в код реальные ссылки на реальные файлы которые физически лежат там где и указано в коде , в .htaccess я прописываю перенапрявление на скрипт PHP с параметром имения файла , скрипт проверяет последнюю дату изменения скрипт и если ничего не изменилось отдает кэш , иначе минифицирует файл ложит в кэш и отдает сжатое :

```
#генератор manifest
RewriteRule (cache.manifest)$  /common/tool/manifest_gen.php  [L]

#минификация js-css
#RewriteRule ^common/(.*).js$  /common/tool/static.php/?filename=$1.js  [L]
#RewriteRule ^common/(.*).css$  /common/tool/static.php/?filename=$1.css  [L]
```

Таким образом даже если к скрипту обращаются напрямую всегда получают сжатую версию.

Answer (score 0):

в папке с файлами которые надо запретить следует разместить файл .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ~ "\.(css|html)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

а вообще пользуйтесь гуглом ответ вот [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26212/htaccess-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%91-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC)