# Заблокировать доступ к папке

Tags: php

Как мне заблокировать доступ к папке если в ней нету нужного аргумента?Например
www.site.ru/papka = доступ запрещен
www.site.ru/papka?что-то =  проходи дорогой

Comment: Для apache ответ тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/26240/186083

Comment: @Visman там закрыть на глухо - а мне нужно что если пришел запрос POST то открывать для скачивания

Comment: Тогда уж заголовок вопроса поменяйте на, хотя бы, `Заблокировать доступ к папке по условию`, а то сбивает с толку.

Answer (score 0):

В файлик .htaccess пишем следующие строки:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule papka/*$ papka_close.php
RewriteRule papka\?.+ papka_open.php
```

так можно направить на разные файлы. Либо можно в конечном файле просто проверить массив $_REQUEST
http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: И получаете полный доступ к физически имеющимся папкам и файлам :)

Comment: Поправьте меня.

Comment: @Max мне нужно , чтобы если было например так www.site.ru/papka = доступ запрещен,а если есть нужный аргумент например www.site.ru/papka?что-то то доступ разрешен