# Заблокировать доступ к папке№!

Tags: php

Как мне заблокировать доступ к папке если в ней нету нужного аргумента`?`Например `www.site.ru/papka = доступ запрещен` 
`www.site.ru/papka?нужный_мне_аргумент = проходи` дорогой срочно

Comment: А как доступ к папке осуществляется? Апачем? PHP-скриптом?

Comment: @IvanBolnikh open server - apache 2.2

Comment: Дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709081/186083

Comment: @Visman потому что дали не тот ответ,что нужно

Comment: Так вам было сказано поменять вопрос, чтобы он был ясен при прочтении, а не создавать новый.

Comment: @Visman всмысле ясен? Carrot--Show прочитал и дал ответ почти такой,какой нужен - почему там не смогли прочесть - неясно

Comment: Когда я читал ваш вопрос, понял следующее: у вас заблокирована папка на доступ (сделано это уже!), но блокировка работает только на адресе `www.site.ru/papka`, а если что-то дописать к этому адресу, то блокировка доступа слетает. Вот так я его понял.

Comment: @Visman мне нужно чтобы доступ к папку работал если указан например нужный аргумент - например www.site.ru/papka?аргумент - в противном случает отказ

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709081/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: @insolor полный вопрос на ответ не был дан ни там,ни тут.

Comment: @Azymok, так нужно добиваться полного ответа в одном вопросе, а не плодить дубли.

Answer (score 0):

Добавте это в начало php скрипта:

```
if(!isset($_GET['аргумент'])) {
   header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
   exit;
}
```

Comment: 0xdb - а если человек переходит просто по пути www.site.ru/papka?файлы то показываются

Comment: а если человек переходит просто по пути www.site.ru/papka?файлы то показываются

Comment: @Azymok, без аргумента не показываются