# Запрет доступности папки по условию

Tags: php, .htaccess, авторизация, доступ

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией: на свой сайт добавляю много лендингов, то есть выглядит как то так http://site.com/land1/ и таких лендов куча. Когда только закидываю на хост папку с лендом то он сразу становится доступен в вебе по имени папки. Хочется сделать так, чтобы он стал доступен только тогда, когда я разрешу.

Comment: `сделать так, чтобы он стал доступен только тогда, когда я разрешу.` - что вы имеете ввиду? Ввод логина/пароля, доступ по ip, etc?

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста вот в этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26212/htaccess-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%91-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC

Comment: Вы можете просто класть такой файл (указав расширения своего контента) в каждую папку, которую хотите закрыть. А когда нужно будет ее открыть - удаляйте этот файл из папки - и она сразу станет видна извне, без перезагрузки веб-сервера

Comment: "сделать так, чтобы он стал доступен только тогда, когда я разрешу" - то есть где то у себя в админке тыкаю "отобразить" и лендинг станет доступен в вебе по своему адресу

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте `Deny from all` в файл `.htaccess` в нужной папке

Comment: Вы дали ответ, который будет работать только при некоторых условиях. Не забывайте их указывать

Comment: @tutankhamun, не понял о каких условиях идёт речь, но да, требуется наличие сервера apache. Наличие файловой системы тоже обязательно. Ну и без электричества работать не будет

Comment: А еще не будет работать в Apache 2.4

Comment: @tutankhamun, работает на 2.4.18

Comment: C mod_access_compat (кстати сам про него не знал). Который не у всех хостеров установлен. Это тоже условие :)

Comment: так дело в том что у меня этих папок сотни, неужели мне придется везде htaccess заводить?

Comment: Вы можете автоматизировать создание и редактирование этого файла скриптом на php и формой в админке